# Styling a word for all documents in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, styles

I'm using a program that generates some files with no extension and I'm opening them to see whether it is related to me or not looking at some words in the file. What I need is some plug-in or built-in solution that highlights some words in documents.

I know I can define my style at NP++ and use it for some file types but as those files don't have an extension I couldn't do it also. 
By the way double clicking that word or right clicking that word and assigning a style is not what I'm looking for. I want the words highlighted when I opened the file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either you just rename the files:

```
ren * *.txt
```

And then proceed with np++

Or you can use findstr:

```
findstr yourword thefolder\*
```

This will show you the files with the line where the match occured.

Comment: I don't want to rename files.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a style to be applied on a document, even if the file extension is not correct.

Click the 'Language' menu to select your language. If you have defined your own language, this will be displayed near the bottom of the list.

This will then highlight the relevant words based on the language you have created.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't define my language for a file which has no file extension.